# Optimize mySQL query combining a sort and a group by

Tags: mysql, optimization, query-optimization

I work on mysql 5.1.

I want to optimize a query it generates from this to this :

- Entry : a 'users' table with an id and a name (100 000 entries)
- Output : the first user_ids for each letter, and their counts

Example :

```
id | name
1  | Bob
2  | Albert
3  | bernard
```

Output :

```
letter | id | count
     A | 2  | 1
     B | 1  | 2
```

The first letter A has 1 users (Albert), the letter B has 2 users (bernard and Bob) ; the first one in alphabetical order is bernard.

I have a working query. It returns all the letters (and the 'no-letters'), with the first user and the count.

```
SELECT formatted_letter, id, COUNT(1)
FROM (
  SELECT
    CASE WHEN name REGEXP '[A-Za-z].*'
           THEN UPPER(SUBSTR(name, 1, 1))
         ELSE '@'
    END as formatted_letter, id, name
  FROM `users`
    ... (some joins and conditions)
  ORDER BY name
) AS A
GROUP BY formatted_letter
```

This works perfectly and returns the correct values... But this query is very time-consuming (9 seconds for a selection of 25 000 users)...

Do you have any other method to optimize this query ?

Things I have tried:

- make a big union for each letter, this is worst (36 seconds).
- Add a column 'formatted_letter' to delete the CASE/WHEN part, it's not bad, it takes now 8 seconds.

All the indexes are present on users ids, users names, and all the indexes for the joins and conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible idea here:-

```
SELECT FirstLetter, MAX(name), SUM(NameCount)
FROM
(
    SELECT substr(name, 1, 1) AS FirstLetter, MIN(name) AS name, COUNT(*) AS NameCount
    FROM company
    GROUP BY FirstLetter
    UNION
    SELECT 'A' AS FirstLetter, "" AS name, 0 AS NameCount
    UNION
    SELECT 'B' AS FirstLetter, "" AS name, 0 AS NameCount
    UNION
    SELECT 'C' AS FirstLetter, "" AS name, 0 AS NameCount
    UNION
    SELECT 'D' AS FirstLetter, "" AS name, 0 AS NameCount
    UNION
    SELECT 'E' AS FirstLetter, "" AS name, 0 AS NameCount
    UNION
    SELECT 'F' AS FirstLetter, "" AS name, 0 AS NameCount
    UNION
    SELECT 'G' AS FirstLetter, "" AS name, 0 AS NameCount
    UNION
    SELECT 'H' AS FirstLetter, "" AS name, 0 AS NameCount
    UNION
    SELECT 'I' AS FirstLetter, "" AS name, 0 AS NameCount
    UNION
    SELECT 'J' AS FirstLetter, "" AS name, 0 AS NameCount
    UNION
    SELECT 'K' AS FirstLetter, "" AS name, 0 AS NameCount
    UNION
    SELECT 'L' AS FirstLetter, "" AS name, 0 AS NameCount
) sub1
GROUP BY FirstLetter
```

(I got bored typing the possible letters to union on to fill in the gaps).

This does work, but not sure of the performance on a table the size of yours (takes under a second on a random table / field I have, with about 140k records).

EDIT - OK trying again.

Your basic query comes down to this (ignoring filling in the blanks):-

```
SELECT CASE WHEN name REGEXP '[A-Za-z].*' THEN UPPER(SUBSTR(name, 1, 1)) ELSE '@' END as formatted_letter, MIN(id) AS id, COUNT(*) AS NameCount
FROM users
GROUP BY formatted_letter
```

This should be pretty efficient on its own. Give that a try and let us know how long it takes.

If that is quick the unions to add the zero count records should add a nominal time.

Trying that on a random table with 140k records it takes about 1 second for me (and the name field isn't even indexed).

Adding on the unioned selects does not add any noticeable time to the query:-

```
SELECT formatted_letter, MAX(name), SUM(NameCount)
FROM
(
    SELECT CASE WHEN company REGEXP '[A-Za-z].*' THEN UPPER(SUBSTR(company, 1, 1)) ELSE '@' END as formatted_letter, MIN(id) AS id, COUNT(*) AS NameCount
    FROM users
    GROUP BY formatted_letter
    UNION
    SELECT 'A' AS formatted_letter, "" AS id, 0 AS NameCount
    UNION SELECT 'B' AS formatted_letter, "" AS id, 0 AS NameCount
    UNION SELECT 'C' AS formatted_letter, "" AS id, 0 AS NameCount
    UNION SELECT 'D' AS formatted_letter, "" AS id, 0 AS NameCount
    UNION SELECT 'E' AS formatted_letter, "" AS id, 0 AS NameCount
    UNION SELECT 'F' AS formatted_letter, "" AS id, 0 AS NameCount
    UNION SELECT 'G' AS formatted_letter, "" AS id, 0 AS NameCount
    UNION SELECT 'H' AS formatted_letter, "" AS id, 0 AS NameCount
    UNION SELECT 'I' AS formatted_letter, "" AS id, 0 AS NameCount
    UNION SELECT 'J' AS formatted_letter, "" AS id, 0 AS NameCount
    UNION SELECT 'K' AS formatted_letter, "" AS id, 0 AS NameCount
    UNION SELECT 'L' AS formatted_letter, "" AS id, 0 AS NameCount
    UNION SELECT 'M' AS formatted_letter, "" AS id, 0 AS NameCount
    UNION SELECT 'N' AS formatted_letter, "" AS id, 0 AS NameCount
    UNION SELECT 'O' AS formatted_letter, "" AS id, 0 AS NameCount
    UNION SELECT 'P' AS formatted_letter, "" AS id, 0 AS NameCount
    UNION SELECT 'Q' AS formatted_letter, "" AS id, 0 AS NameCount
    UNION SELECT 'R' AS formatted_letter, "" AS id, 0 AS NameCount
    UNION SELECT 'S' AS formatted_letter, "" AS id, 0 AS NameCount
    UNION SELECT 'T' AS formatted_letter, "" AS id, 0 AS NameCount
    UNION SELECT 'U' AS formatted_letter, "" AS id, 0 AS NameCount
    UNION SELECT 'V' AS formatted_letter, "" AS id, 0 AS NameCount
    UNION SELECT 'W' AS formatted_letter, "" AS id, 0 AS NameCount
    UNION SELECT 'X' AS formatted_letter, "" AS id, 0 AS NameCount
    UNION SELECT 'Y' AS formatted_letter, "" AS id, 0 AS NameCount
    UNION SELECT 'Z' AS formatted_letter, "" AS id, 0 AS NameCount
    UNION SELECT '@' AS formatted_letter, "" AS id, 0 AS NameCount
) Sub1
GROUP BY formatted_letter
```

If this takes 36 seconds or so on you machine then something strange is happening

Comment: I explain on my post that I already tried this idea... And this is worst !

Comment: This is only merging in the extra letters onto the end (with the zero counts). It should be pretty efficient as it will only be dealing with a tiny number of rows by this stage. I assumed in your original post you were doing the whole query once for each letter and then merging those results together (which would be slow)

Comment: I read too fast your first response, which differs from my method... Yours is effectively faster, and takes only 1.2 seconds for my entire base, 1.3 with my joins and conditions. It will be ok ! Thanks !

Comment: Glad to help. Your idea of adding an indexed formatted first letter column would be compatible with this and might also help a touch (get it below 1 second and it probably stops appearing on the slow query log).

Comment: The times I give you on my previous comments are with a new column "formatted_letter", automatically updated and indexed.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by the 'no-letters', and the from (other joins/conditions) if exposed might be able to be optimized too.  At a MINIMUM, do you have just the name... or at least the name in the first position?

Also, I would kill the inner ORDER BY NAME clause as that has no actual bearing on the final output where you are doing the group by the formatted_letter anyhow...  Add the order by formatted_letter at the outer query since that would only return the 26 + '@' records and would be instant.

Comment: The users belongs to several groups ; I used a JOIN and a WHERE to select only users from a set of groups. The "no-letters" are the names that doesn't begin with /[A-Z0-9]/, like "@" or "$".

Comment: @ForgetTheNorm, then I might consider moving the GROUPS qualifying condition to the front position and only get those names that qualify.  Again, without seeing that relationship/criteria, not sure if that can be optimized further.